# How to partition a table in Databricks by data-size/row count not by column

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I've seen databricks examples that use the `partionBy` method. But partitions are recommended to be 128MB. I'd think there was a way to basically achieve that as closely as possible? Take the total size, divide it by 128mb, then partition by a *number of partitions* rather than by a dimension.

Any suggestions for how this is achieved would be appreciated.

Comment: are you looking this option : spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes?

Comment: As I understand - you read data from another database? What do you use - JDBC? If yes, show how do you read the data?

Comment: Yeah read in with JDBC

Answer (score 2):

The setting `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` has indeed impact on the max size of the partitions when reading the data on the Spark cluster.By using this configuration we can control the partition based on the size of the data .

Comment: This feels close, but looking at the doc this behaves more like an upper bound on how big to make the partitions. But I'd need to find a column that would partition at least datasize/128 ways.
My situation is I read over 10TB of data from another database. But operations are slow, and I don't want to manually find partitions. It feels like there should be some default setting. I'm still new to spark though. Any advice is welcome.